# convert character column into datetime column in r , "04/19/19 08:46 " this value is in character i need to get this in date time?

Tags: r

i have this "04/19/19 08:46"value in Order.Date column. Order.date column is in character type but i want that column to be in datetime type.how can i do that.
the name of the dataframe is re_dat_csv3.

```
Order.ID.......Product...................Quantity.Order.....Price.Each.......Order.Date......Purchase.Address

176558........USB-C Charging Cable..........2...........11.95.......04/19/19 08:46.....1st St, Dallas, TX 75001

176559........Bose Sound t Headphones....1.........99.99......04/07/19 22:30    .....682 Chestnut St, Boston, MA 02215

176560.......Google Phone.........................1.......  600.00....04/12/19 14:38......669 Spruce St, Los Angeles, CA 90001
```

i have tried to show it as a table.So please don't get confused.

Comment: You need the `as.POSIXct()` function. For example, try `as.POSIXct("04/19/19 08:46", format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`. Your may also want to look at the `lubridate` package.

Comment: You can use `dput` to get your data as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `as.POSIXct`

```
df$Order.Date <- with(df, as.POSIXct(Order.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
```